# Assembly .byte and offset instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, byte, offset, low-level

I have a question about some code. What's the output of this program and why? Could somebody explain this to me step by step with focus on offset and .byte instructions?

```
.intel_syntax noprefix 
    .text 
    .globl main 
main: 
    push ebx 
    mov ebx, offset x 
    add ebx, 3 
    mov al, [ebx] 
    xor ah, ah 
    pop ebx 
    ret

.data
x:
    .byte 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8
```

Comment: Related: [Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel\_syntax](//stackoverflow.com/q/39355188) explains how/why assembles to `mov ebx, offset x` assembles to `mov ebx, imm32` with the absolute address (of the symbol/label) as an immediate operand.

Comment: [What is the use of .byte assembler directive in gnu assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7290318) explains how `.byte` assembles literal data into the output file.

Comment: I didn't find a close enough duplicate for the OFFSET part to close this as a duplicate of 2 other questions.  But see also [mov instructions with byte destination for immediate to memory](//stackoverflow.com/q/17221452). for an example of how `mov reg, OFFSET symbol` assembles + links.